# Bootstrap and images: What are the best dimensions to pre-resized images for a design implemented with Bootstrap?

Tags: image, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm using a CMS (read: WordPress). While I realize that Bootstrap will adjust img sizing on the fly, should I (for example) have WP create a version of an image for each BS span# width? Or do you think having span2, span4, span6, etc. would be close enough and just just the slightly larger image for the next span down. For example, if you need an image in a span1, would you simply use the span2 image?

I'm trying to balance image size against being practical and reasonable.

Perhaps this isn't a StackoverFlow question? My apologizes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are no such limitations or ideal sizes. People can use larger than 1000px width images or lower than 50px as well. It is the beauty of bootstrap, it automatically resizes image if the span width is smaller than image width.

So that should not really bother us while developing the theme. One thing you can take care of is, measure the most used span's width in Web developers tool and set ideal image size little smaller than span width.

You don't need another function to resize images. It would be an overkill.

Comment: for load speed images should be as lean as possible. putting (for example) an image with a width=1000px into a span2 spot is a waste. bootstrap does not "resize", it adjusts the display dimensions. again, this could slow page load speed. with all due respect, this is an issue for good / better theme developers.